# subprocess.Popen, get variable from subprocess (child)

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I would like to know how i can handle it, that i get a variable/value from the subprocess to the parent.

I am running the subprocess as an script. **The parent looks like:**

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('abaqus python getData.py', shell=True)
p_status = p.wait()
print b
```

**The child looks like:**

```
from numpy import *

if __name__ == "__main__":

    b = [0,1,2,3]  # output is a list of integers
    global a = b
```

I am totally new to python. I think the problem is, that i can not store variables this way and make them "public" to the parent? Do i have to write them in a *.txt or something like that and get them with numpy.loadtxt()?

Comment: those are 2 different processes. You cannot share the data like this. do you _really_ have to create another process?

Comment: @Jean yeahh, i have to do so, cause abaqus works with his own python compiler and package "odbAccess". with that i can wrap data from an *.odb file, but i can not import the package "metaplotlib" as needed. so i start the python compiler, run the abaqus python compiler through the parant and would like to give the values back to the parent, so that i can make some plots from the data. btw. i am sorry for my english.

Comment: what is the type of the object you're returning from the subprocess?

Comment: its a list with integers

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre any idea how I can handle that? Thanks :)

Comment: If it's just a list of integers, they're easy to serialize -- ie. pass over stdout.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, could u be so kind and give me a short example? I am really totally new to python. Thank you very much. If u got no time, it’s ok. I will check google for that. ^^

Comment: An example is already available to you: The answer by Jean-François Fabre does what I propose, serializing the array as a Python datastructure, printing it to stdout, and parsing it in the parent. (If you wanted to be able to implement one component or the other in a language other than Python, I'd suggest standardizing on JSON instead).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the subprocess is a python process, you cannot communicate between them using global variables.

You cannot use a `multiprocessing.Manager` object either since you need 2 distinct python engines (with separate capabilities).

The classic (and easy) way is to serialize your data using a simple `print` (since you have a list of integers in output), and deserialize using `ast.literal_eval` (`json` would also be possible)

Callee (`getData.py` mockup):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print([1,2,3,4])  # mock output
```

Caller:

```
import subprocess,ast
output = subprocess.check_output('abaqus python getData.py', shell=True)
lst = ast.literal_eval(output.decode("ascii"))
```

now `lst` contains `[1,2,3,4]`

If your output data is more complex (list of lists, dictionaries...) just compose the list of lists, dictionary with nested dicts inside, ... and print that. `ast.literal_eval` is able to rebuild the same structure on the other side.

Comment: Might be good practice to show how one would avoid the reliance on `shell=True` by passing arguments as an array.

Comment: I will check this later. Thank you very much. :) Is there a way to hide the print? That I can run the Print in “Background”.

Comment: the `print` will be hidden, because `check_output` consumes it without printing it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ok, that’s pretty cool! You are my personal hero of the evening.  Thanks!

Comment: my pleasure. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: i am not that sure, if this works for multiple prints? i mean, if i would have like 3 arrays.

Comment: if you have 3 arrays, put them in a list, print that: done. That's the point of serializing like this. you can serialize complex structures like dictionaries, list of lists, list of dictionaries with multiple levels...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so i can build up an complex structured array? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes, if you use only lists, strings, ints, floats, bools, dicts, tuples... basic types. Try it.