# Parsing python variable retrieved from subprocess powershell function

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to get a variable from powershell to python. I am testing a powershell function where I receive some data from a remote email server, then I am trying to pipe back the results with a return statement.

Python script:

```
import subprocess
import ast
data = subprocess.check_output(["pwsh", "/app/functions/intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1","emaillist"])
print(data)
```

Powershell script:

```
function emaillist{
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "SOMELONGPASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("email@email.com", $password)
    $ses = New-PSSession -Name "email@email.com" -ConnectionUri https://exchange.intermedia.net/powershell -ConfigurationName Hosting.PowerShell -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic
    Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {Set-ConnectionSettings -CredentialType "User" -Credential $Using:Cred -AccountID 000000}
    $userdata = Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {Get-User}
    return $userdata
}
```

I was able to pipe the output but it comes out very weird.
[image]

I googled the error and got this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48214116 So I tried to convert this using `ast` but I kept getting an error when it tried to parse the weird data.

```
lst = ast.literal_eval(data.decode("ascii"))
```

but I got an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 12202: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? `Get-User` is returning a PS object for the user. What information are you trying to get from Exchange online? [here's some of the information on the object return from `get-user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-user?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: You CAN pipe `get-user` into `ConvertTo-Json` which might be a bit easier to work with in python.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution own my own. Simply convert the data into json format and then you use json loads on the python side to parse the data.

powershell script:

```
function emaillist{
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "SOMELONGPASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("email@email.com", $password)
    $ses = New-PSSession -Name "email@email.com" -ConnectionUri https://exchange.intermedia.net/powershell -ConfigurationName Hosting.PowerShell -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic
    Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {Set-ConnectionSettings -CredentialType "User" -Credential $Using:Cred -AccountID 000000}
    $userdata = Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {Get-User} | ConvertTo-Json
    return $userdata
}
```

Python script:

```
import subprocess
import json
data = subprocess.check_output(["pwsh", "/app/functions/intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1","emaillist"])
data_loads = json.loads(data)
print(data_loads)
```

**EDIT** - It seems the stackoverflow user `another victim of the mouse` just copied my answer to make his own. You can tell by the timing of the comment and his post that he just copied my answer after I already found the answer for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's reusable function:

```
function Get-JsonEmailList { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [String]
        $target
    )
    $email = 'email@email.com'
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'SOMELONGPASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
    $Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($email, $password)
    $ses = New-PSSession -Name $email -ConnectionUri https://exchange.intermedia.net/powershell -ConfigurationName Hosting.PowerShell -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic
    Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock { Set-ConnectionSettings -CredentialType 'User' -Credential $Using:Cred -AccountID 000000 }
    $userdata = Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock { Get-User $target | ConvertTo-Json } 
    return $userdata
}

get-JsonEmailList
```